# Connect react app on firebase hosting and firebase cloud functions v2

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have Vite react app (that perfectly works locally) with the config that redirects all api requests starts with `/functions` to firebase function via url (express app).

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/functions': {
        target: FIREBASE_CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_URL,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/functions/, ''),
      },
    }
  }
})
```

My firebase v2 function is deployed and available in the **europe-west3** region

[image]

All my API endpoints available via next urls:

- `https://functions-someid-ey.a.run.app/someMethod1`
- `https://functions-someid-ey.a.run.app/someMethod2`
- `https://functions-someid-ey.a.run.app/someMethod3`

Now I am trying to deploy my react app into Firebase Hosting with the same behaviour. I follow [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

My firebase.json looks as follows:

```
{

  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/functions/**",
        "function": {
          "functionId": "functions",
          "region": "europe-west3"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But all api calls after deployment returns `404`:

- `https://PROJECT_ID.web.app/functions/someMethod1`
- `https://PROJECT_ID.web.app/functions/someMethod2`
- `https://PROJECT_ID.web.app/functions/someMethod3`

What I am missing? How properly to setup redirects/rewrites from hosting to cloud function v2? Maybe I am using wrong identifier for `functionId` (I am using just function name). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that firebase rewrite just passes the full url to the function:

`https://PROJECT_ID.web.app/functions/someMethod1 -> /functions/someMethod`

Your express app should hosts `/functions/someMethod` (mine was just `/someMethod`)